# download of Python(x,y)-2.7.6.1.exe blocked by Antivirus

Tags: pythonxy

today I tried to download Python(x,y)-2.7.6.1.exe (https://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/wiki/Downloads?tm=2), but the download was blocked by my Avast free Antivirus because of a Trojan Horse ("Win32:Dropper-gen [Drp]").
Does anybody else has this problem?

Comment: That program is big enough (700+MB!) that it might contain something that tickled the AV. If the file is from a reputable source, it should be fine. Check hashes and signatures if you are able.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I did a quick search for `virus` under the project issues, and found there's an [open item](https://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/issues/detail?id=728) for this (as well as a [merged issue](https://code.google.com/p/pythonxy/issues/detail?id=740) with the exact trojan you're seeing reported); most recent comment from the developer on June 8th:

> It seems like a false positive - see:
>
> https://www.virustotal.com/en/file/761c7bb7e7b12e3a9cd535290d7df704a202cc6b4330a08e1ed3350b74f117e1/analysis/1402239893/
>
> I've submitted a false positive report which hopefully will clear things up.